# How to resize image using imagemagick?

Tags: c#, imagemagick, image-manipulation, image-resizing

When I resize image using imagemagick then it shown like cropped.
I using below code for resize image

```
ImageMagickObject.MagickImage imgLarge = new ImageMagickObject.MagickImage();
 object[] o = new object[] { "image_Input.jpg", "-resize", size, "-gravity", "center", "-colorspace", "RGB", "-extent", "100x100", "image_Output.jpg" };
imgLarge.Convert(ref o);
```

See the below image before image resize
[image]

See the below image after image resize it shown below

[image]

I exactly want that resize image shown full image as shown before re-sized.
in my output image it goes to like cropped not shown full view of the input image.. 
 How I can do?

Comment: @CharlesB Thanks for remove unused tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is becuase you use following parameters:

```
-gravity center -extent 100x100
```

Above params talk to ImageMagick: "Extract, please, area with size 100x100 from center of my image. For more details you can read [command line options documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php).

So, sulution is following args:

```
image_Input.jpg -resize 100x100 image_Output.jpg
```

From my practice:

I am not using image magick wrapper for .net, because it was 32 bit (at least a half of year ago) and it cause different problems.

In general in web applications usual need only two operations: 
*1.Resize* 
*2.Crop* 
Above commands use only one exe file: `convert.exe`.

So i've done small wrapper thats run convert.exe with arguments.

MB a little later i post here github url to wrapper project if someone interest in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

1) convert youractualimage.png -resize 200x200 newimage.png

This will resize image in aspect ration.

To create image of exact dimension 200x200, you could use

2) convert youractualimage.png -resize 200x200! newimage.png